# <SOLVED>BoomMenu Bug while trying to navigate to other fragment in android studio

Tags: android-studio, navigateurl

Is there a solution for a bug in BMB to navigate to other fragment in Android Studio?
Because it took a very long time to go to other fragment
my code are

image:

Comment: Add your code example

Comment: show us the code, to understand the problem

Comment: builder.normalImageRes(R.drawable.icon_rainmeter).normalColorRes(R.color.color1).normalText("Tips Rainmeter").listener(object :
                    OnBMClickListener {
                    override fun onBoomButtonClick(index: Int) {
                        bmb.hideMoveEaseEnum

                        view!!.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_home2_to_cuaca_panas)
                    }
                })

Comment: Edit your question and past your code in question body please. There are limitation in comments